# Chrome extension that open a new tab with a link

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to open a new tab from a chrome extension. I searched here but nothing I've found seem to solve this.

I simply want it to open a tab on a button click.

**manifest**
        {
      "manifest_version": 2,

```
  "name": "TestExtension",
  "description": "La LA LA",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html:**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main" class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="doItBtn">Do it NOW!        
  </body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var btn = document.getElementsById("doItBtn");
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: "http://www.ynet.co.il"});
    });
});
```

I tried not putting the code in a backgorund.js but simple script tag instead but didn't work to.

What did I do wrong?

Regards,
Ido

Comment: You don't need a background script. Rename your `background.js` as `popup.js`, include `<script src="popup.js"></script>` at the end of your `popup.html` file, right before the `</body>` tag, and remove the `"background"` entry from your manifest file.

Comment: I get:   Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Comment: Use `document.getElementById` not `getElementsById` which doesn't exists